# Nested transaction in ejb sessionbean - bean managed transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I have the following code which saves the user and sends a JMS message. Currently im wraping the `saveUserSendMessage` with the UserTransaction. When the transaction is nested I get a exception in the ejb. What do I do below to make the nested transaction possible?

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/JmsXA")
private static QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory;

@Resource(mappedName = "EjbQueueJndi")
private static Queue queueProp;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ejbPersistanceunit")
private EntityManager em;

@Resource
UserTransaction ut;

@Override
public boolean saveUserSendMessage(String name, String email, int age,
        boolean arg3) throws Exception {

    UserTransaction xact = ut;
    xact.begin();

    saveUser(name, email, age);
    sendMessage("Successfully saved the user");
    try {
        if (arg3)
            throw new Exception("Unsuccessfull");
        xact.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        xact.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean saveUser(String name, String email, int age)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        ut.begin();
        UserEntity ue = new UserEntity();
        ue.setAge(age);
        ue.setEmail(email);
        ue.setName(name);
        em.persist(ue);
        ut.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Exception i get:

```
15:51:04,127 ERROR [STDERR] javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - [com.arjuna
.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.alreadyassociated] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.alreadya
ssociated] thread is already associated with a transaction!
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that, using Bean-managed Transactions.  It's possible within container-managed transactions, but even then not within the same method.

Comment: You mean same class? /

Comment: I meant method.  Using CMT, and a method that has a RequiresNew should support nested transactions, but even with CMT all the code performed within that method will be in a single transaction.  I guess it's possible if the same object is called through the service layer, that if it calls another method with it's own RequiresNew definition, it could use a new transaction.  But all of this is CMT, and the literature doesn't state that any of this is possible for BMT

Comment: Whats the behavior you are trying to achieve, as its not obvious? Why you want nested transactions?

Comment: @Gas I have two methods(A,B) and each one of it will be called independently. but A uses B to save user into db and then sends a jms message. There are cases when only B will be called. So, if you see I need to put transasction boundaries in both the methods. Now I know it cannot be done, i'll probably wrap this common method B around another method C and make B a private to this bean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java EE does not support nested transactions.  The only thing it supports is suspending a transaction, running an unrelated transaction, and the resuming the first transaction.

To accomplish that, you would need to call another EJB that uses RequiresNew transaction attribute.  Note that the inner transaction can complete even if the message receipt rolls back, which means if the messaging engine crashes, the second transaction might be run again.  Alternatively, you could change the EJB to use bean-managed transactions, which would have a similar effect.

Are you sure you really want to do that? It's probably best to just execute the logic within the container-managed transaction.